# What is AMI BIOS VR Noise Mitigation doing? Does it have impact on the fan?

Tags: bios

I have recently bought a MINI PC (NiPoGi GX3). In the BIOS it has the `CPU VR Settings`, and there under `Accoustic Noise Settings/Accoustic Noise Mitigation`.

I could not find any **FAN** settings in the BIOS. What is this `Accoustic Noise Mitigation` actually doing, can I enable it to reduce fan noise? And why is that under VR, I assume VR is the Virtualization section, or am I wrong here?

[image: Processor]

Comment: It’s probably about coil whine.

Comment: Motherboard always has a Voltage Regulator module for providing power to the CPU, it has inductors (coils) that probably can buzz...

Comment: I see, VR -> voltage regulator! Thanks to you both!

Comment: What type of processor do you have exactly?

Comment: N95 Alder Lake, added screenshot